# Adding a node to Neo4J database using cypher ExecutionEngine

Tags: neo4j, cypher, owl

Created the database as follows:

```
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( "D:/TestGraphDatabase" );
 cypherEngine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb, null);
```

Attempted to add a node in the following manner:

```
            String parentString = "Thing";
            String uri = "XXX";
            String queryString = "MERGE (owl:{name} {uri: {uri}, name: {name}}) RETURN n";
            Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put( "name", parentString );
            parameters.put( "uri", uri );
            resultIterator = (ResourceIterator<Node>) cypherEngine.execute(queryString, parameters).columnAs("n");

            result = resultIterator.next();
            tx.success();
            return result;
```

This gives me a null pointer exception:
at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.planQuery(ExecutionEngine.scala:85)at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:75)at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:71)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have experience with the Cypher ExecutionEngine directly but I know that the Cypher REST API doesn't allow a label (in this case, `:{name}`) to be a parameter. Also, your query seems to return something called `n` but there is no such identifier in the rest of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to pass a StringLogger.DEV_NULL during the ExecutionEngine initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ExecutionEngine in the javacompat package not the other one (which is from Scala).

Then also the results will be easy to handle.

see: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html

where it says:

#### Caution:

*The classes used here are from the org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat package, not org.neo4j.cypher, see link to the Java API below.*